# Fresh meteor 1.3 on win7 not runnning

Tags: node.js, meteor, http-proxy

I am also posting this on stackoverflow as this is suggested by meteor itself :)

I upgraded my meteor project to Meteor 1.3, and after updating all the proper packages I could not get meteor 1.3 to run. Then I created a fresh project and still get this error I posted below. I also tried to create the simple-todos example shown here https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app in CMD. Same result.

Windows 7 btw :) Also I have not installed meteorhacks:npm or any other extra packages whatsoever.

```
http.js:733
  throw new TypeError('The header content contains invalid characters');
        ^
TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:733:13)
    at new ClientRequest (http.js:1429:14)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:1899:10)
    at Array.stream [as 3] (C:\Users\Lightspeed\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\passes\web-incoming.js:108:74)
at ProxyServer.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lightspeed\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\index.js:80:21)
at Proxy._tryHandleConnections (C:\tools\runners\run-proxy.js:182:20)
at Server.<anonymous> (C:\tools\runners\run-proxy.js:50:12)
at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2164:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:152:23)
at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:2022:22)
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
```

Meteor does startup properly and does not crash until I actually navigate to localhost:3000. The page immediately errors (host not reachable) and meteor crashes with the error shown in my OP.

Comment: Do you have head tags anywhere in your project? If so can you add the code for them?

Comment: @PhilipPryde   
The code I am testing right now is the exact todo example app supplied by meteor. The <head> looks liks this:
<head>
  <title>simple</title>
</head>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was related to a specific windows 7 version. Though I don't have specifics anymore, it has been resolved.